# Can you gain achievements while in Offline Practice Mode?

Tags: steam, achievements, team-fortress-2

Can Steam Achievements in Team Fortress 2 be awarded if you are playing in Offline/Training mode, or is it just training?

**(I am online, it's just that the Offline Practice is playing with Bots.)**

Comment: In CS:Global Offensive you could,don't know if TF2 works the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides the one training mode achievement, no, you can't.

Considering you are online, you could create an empty server for yourself and add some bots (`tf_bot_add`) to it (just make sure `sv_cheats = 0`). I've gotten a few achievements this way. Also, be sure that you're using a supported bot map, otherwise you'll need to use `nav_generate`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can only gain achievements online. Plus must of the achievements require you to be online. Really. I have all the TF2 achievements, so I know.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, but just because you have all the TF2 achievements doesn't mean you did any of them offline. Perhaps you could supply a better proof for your answer?

Comment: @Mufasa I think you are right, but I just did the Second Degree Burn achievement properly, but I didn't get it in Offline Mode. It's probably only in online servers.